# How and where to set Access-Control-Expose-Headers for koa-cors

Tags: header, cors, fetch, koa

I am attempting to get some headers sent from my server to my front end via a fetch request.

In the controller function, I am explicitly sending some headers like this:

```js
exports.getItems = async (ctx) => {
  ctx.set('Search-type', 'category');
};
```

In postman, when I make a get request to my server I get these headers:

```js
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →6442
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Thu, 19 Apr 2018 16:10:54 GMT
Search-type →category
```

However, when I try to access the header in the fetch request from the front end, I can only log the Content-Type. How do I get Search-type from my fetch?

After some googling, I found this [issue on github](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/399) which seems very similar to mine. This led me to another [github issue page](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/67) with the suggestion that I need to 'expose some explicitly needed headers'.

In the [koa/cors](https://github.com/koajs/cors) documentation, there is an option `allowHeaders Access-Control-Allow-Headers` what I want to know is, how do I expose the headers so I can get them on my front end?

Answer (score 0):

In the response to the GET, in addition to adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, you also need to include the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: <comma-separated-list-of-headers>` response header.

If that header isn't returned by the server, even though the headers are sent by the server to the browser, the browser blocks any non-standard headers from being accessed by JavaScript. So you can see `Content-Type` (because it's a 'standard' response header), but not `Search-type`.

Basically, you need to ensure that the server responds with this

`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Search-type`

(in addition to any other CORS response headers, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, of course).

Comment: But where do I assign this Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Search-type? like ctx.set(Access-Control-Expose-Headers, 'Search-type') my problem is I don't know where to put this thing...

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure - the koa/cors documentation looks like it's as simple as setting `options.exposeHeaders` to a value of `"Search-type"`, but I admit I've never used that package.